# How to import modules in android studio?

Tags: android, module, android-module

I am importing new module which have another module inside it also, into another project but the **finish** button not working?

Do anyone has solution for that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the settings.gradle directly, like:

```
include ':gpuv'
```

Then Sync the gradle and build the project

Comment: Do I needed to copy paste the module folder into that project's directory?